# All floats in a single function with call by reference

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    float peri ,area1;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    area(x, &peri, &area1);
    printf(" %f %f ", peri, area1);
    return 0;
}

int area(int r, float *per, float *are)
{
    *per = 2.0 * r;
    *are = 3.14 * r * r;
}
```

This works fine but when I try to change the input value to float

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float x, peri, area1;
    scanf("%f",&x);
    float area(x, &peri, &area1);
    printf(" %f %f ", peri, area1);
    return 0;
}

float area(float r, float *per, float *are)
{
    *per = 2.0 * r;
    *are = 3.14 * r * r;
}
```

I get:

> error: expected ')' before '&' token

Comment: i want to know but for int i don't have to declare such a function outside main why is that so

Comment: You should change the floating point literals 2.0 etc to 2.0f. 2.0 means double type, 2.0f means float type. In case of the former, you enforce the compiler to convert your float to a double before calculating, then round it down into a float once more, possibly resulting in less efficient code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 float area( x, &peri, &area1);
```

should be

```
area( x, &peri, &area1);
```

You don't need to specify the return type when you are calling the function.

Also since the return type now is non-int you need to either:

1. Move the function definition before main.
2. Provide a function declaration like:

   ```
   float area(float, float *, float *);
   ```

   before main.

Also since you are **not returning anything** from the function you should be making its return type as `void`.

Comment: I suspect that a function that is declared to return something, but doesn't, invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
float area( x, &peri, &area1);
```

declares a function, While what you are trying to do is to call the function so it should be:

```
area( x, &peri, &area1);
```

Answer (score 2):

another thing here....  rather than passing by reference,  if you separate out your calculations into different functions...

your area function should turn into  (and be declared above your main function) :-

```
float area_of_circle( float radius)
{
   return 3.14 * radius * radius;
}

float perimeter_of_circle(float radius)
{
   return 2 * 3.14 * radius;
}
```

then in your main code

```
peri = perimeter_of_circle(x);
area1 = area_of_circle(x);
```

Note, I also fixed the bug in calculating a perimeter.

Basically a function should do one thing, and do it well.

Ideally you'd also  make a  #define (or #include an existing definition) for pi.

also, your scanfing for a int,  you may want to get a float.

another general commentary on coding,  don't be a lazy ass with naming things.  Not only does naming things help it be readable.  It actually helps you be clear in your mind what you are trying to do.  In fact sometimes by agonizing over what to name something, you end up with clarity of thought, which translates into simple useful abstract concepts in the code.  Which leads to better designs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the keyword float from this line

```
float area( x, &peri, &area1);
```